# Display MySQL-Data on Hover

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, database

I have a MySQL `output-script` on my website:

```
$db_projects = "rex_projects";

$sql = new rex_sql;

$sql->debugsql = 0; //Ausgabe Query

$sql->setQuery("SELECT * FROM $db_projects ORDER BY id");

for($i=0; $i < $sql->getRows(); $i++)
{

    $id = $sql->getValue("id");
    $projectname = $sql->getValue("projectname");
    $projectnumber = $sql->getValue("projectnumber");

    $print_projects .= '<div id="'.$id.'">'.$projectname.' has the number '.$projectnumber.'';

    $sql->next();
}
```

Every database-element is displayed in a div with the formatting above.

**What I would like to implement:**

If I'm hovering a div, another div (code below) should display the specific datasets for this element. Is this possible and which is the easiest to do that?

```
<div id="specific-informations">
    Projectname: <?php echo $projectname ?><br>
    Projectnumber: <?php echo $projectnumber ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't you get an error with your current php? `<div id="'.id.'">` shouldn't that be `<div id="'.$id.'">`? Missing **$** in front of id?

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding below Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){$( "#specific-informations" ).hide();
});
$( "#getinfo" ).mouseover(function() {
    $( "#specific-informations" ).fadeIn(2000);
});
$( "#getinfo" ).mouseout(function() {
    $( "#specific-informations" ).fadeOut(2000);
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bardtdfm/1/)

Comment: This is not the result i want to have. The div is displayed all the time. In the div should appears the specific MySQL datasets.

Comment: If a am hovering the div with the id "3", the div with the id "specific-informations" should display all datasets form the third mysql-table element.

Comment: you want to change the content of div?

Comment: the content inside the div.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like :

Create your second div in $print_projects

```
$print_projects .= <<<HTML
    <div id="$id" class="project">
        $projectname  has the number $projectnumber
        <div class="specific-informations">
            Projectname: $projectname<br>
            Projectnumber: $projectnumber
        </div>
    </div>
HTML;
```

And in your CSS

```
.specific-informations { display: none; }
.project:hover .specific-informations { display: block }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call an ajax function and return the results.Then bind the corresponding ajax data in div.